# Calculate proper Time difference between minutes in SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I need to calculate the difference between the time from 15:00 to 16:00 in Minutes. If the callend exceeds 16:00:00 then i don't want to calculate it in between 15:00 to 16:00 and it should calculate in 16:00 to 17:00

I am using the below query to calculate in SQL

```
select SUM(datediff(second, callstart, callend))diff from tablex where    
CAST(callstart as TIME) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
```

I am getting the results

```
diff
14
```

But I need the result 4. If the callstart and callend is in between 15:58 to 16:09 then I need to take the specific exceeded time to next column like diff16to17. For example i need to carry forward the time 9mins from 15:58 to 16:09 this to diff16to17 column

This is my table

```
    callstart                    callend
 2017-02-01 15:59:38.997    2017-02-01 16:09:39.833
 2017-02-01 15:56:47.720    2017-02-01 15:59:38.527
 2017-02-01 15:55:23.573    2017-02-01 15:56:47.207
```

Comment: Which SQL engine?

Comment: SQL 2012 Professional

Comment: I can't really follow your narrative - can you add another table to your question showing the expected result for each row? (Which would then be `SUM()`ed to get your final result, but I'm not sure what's happening to each row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include the condition on callend in your `WHERE`

```
WHERE CAST(callstart as TIME) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
  AND CAST(callend as TIME) < '16:00:00'
```

If this is a time-based billing calculation, you will need to figure out what the requirements are for the case where a call lasts over an hour, because as it is now they will not be included in any sum

To instead sum the minutes in the call that occur in an hour window, something like

```
WITH window AS
(    SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(callstart as TIME) < '15:00:00' THEN '15:00:00' ELSE callstart END as windowstart, 
            CASE WHEN CAST(callend as TIME) > '16:00:00' THEN '16:00:00' ELSE callend END as windowend
    FROM tablex
    WHERE CAST(callstart as TIME) < '16:00:00' AND CAST(callend as TIME) > '15:00:00'
)
SELECT SUM(datediff(second, windowstart, windowend)) as diff FROM window
```

Comment: okay that's fine. If the callstart and callend is in between 15:58 to 16:09 then I need to take the specific exceeded time to next column like diff16to17. For example i need to carry forward the time 9mins from 15:58 to 16:09 this to diff16to17 column

Answer (score 1):

If i got it right

```
select sum(datediff(second,
                 case when CAST(callend as TIME) >='16:00:00'
                 then '16:00:00' else CAST(callstart as TIME) end
                 , CAST(callend as TIME)))  diff 

from (
    -- example data
    values
     ('2017-02-01 15:59:38.997','2017-02-01 16:09:39.833'),
     ('2017-02-01 15:56:47.720','2017-02-01 15:59:38.527'),
     ('2017-02-01 15:55:23.573','2017-02-01 15:56:47.207')
    )tablex(callstart, callend)

where    
CAST(callstart as TIME) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '16:00:00';
```